# IPTW for multiple treatment options

Tags: r, propensity-scores

I am dealing with a dataset which patients with 3 different types of treatment. Since the baseline characteristics are significantly different and biased, I need to match the baselines. However, the number of each group is too small to match using PSM.
I tried to use `mnps` and `iptw` functions of `twang` package, but I cannot join the two functions and failed to generate the new table 1.

How can I use `iptw` function with `mnps`?

Comment: i've miss written twang as hwang

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `WeightIt` to generate the weights and `cobalt` to assess balance? `WeightIt` supports many methods to estimate weights for multi-category treatments, including generalized boosted models like in `twang` but also many other methods that you should try as well. `cobalt` provides balance tables and plots for multi-category (as well as binary and continuous) treatments. There is no reason to stick to `twang` unless you really like its functionality and know you want GBM.